# Zend project access only main page

Tags: php, zend-framework

I can access only main page in Zend project, however, the rest of pages, I am getting. error, page not found, 404. Even I am running sample zend project. Could anyone help to fix this issue.

Comment: Please specify your environment. (OS, server software, PHP version, ZF version and whether remote or local)

Answer (score 2):

You should check the following as they are the most common causes of this:-

1. .htaccess file is correct and in the right place
2. .htaccess is enabled in httpd.conf (`AllowOverride Any` is set for the `Directory` entry the Zend project is in)
3. mod-rewrite is turned on in httpd.conf
4. The module/controller/action you are trying to access actually exists.
5. There is a view script for the module/controller/action you are trying to access.

If they are all correct then your app should work.